# How can I make sure any data I grab from a spreadsheet has no xml content?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, win32com

I am grabbing data from an excel powerquery which is grabbing from an SQL database. (not the best way to go about it but it works for me at the moment.)

From that data spreadsheet, I am searching for specific job numbers and related numbers to automatically enter into a custom spreadsheet.

Then I want to automatically open, calculate, save, then close excel to have all the formula be calculated and saved.

What I am running into is that **sometimes**, the data grabbed from the spreadsheet is perfectly fine, and other times it has some sort of xml content that makes the automatic excel work fail at the open step.

The grabbing of data uses openpyxl
Much of it looks like this.

```py
wb[sheet]['E11'].value = wbd['XXXXX'].cell(row=YYYYY, column=7).value
wb[sheet]['E12'].value = wbd['XXXXX'].cell(row=YYYYY, column=8).value
```

or like this.

```py
#after getting a dictionary of the relevant values.
thisCost = 0
for _ in costTypeDictionary[AAAAA]['BBBBB'].split():
    thisCost += CCCCC.get(_,0)
costs += thisCost
```

The excel automatic bit is as follows

```py
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(saveLoc + "\\" + jobName + newFileXlsx)
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

It works some of the time. data is grabbed, no issues. But on other occasions excel produces errors such as the following.

*please note that there are no named ranges in any spreadsheet being opened or used by openpyxl*
`Removed Feature: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)`

the python automation also produces an error in the pywintypes module.
`pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`

So from what I am seeing, as manual inspection of the data is revealing nothing noticeable/I don't know what to look for, is that there is an extra something in the `bad` set of data that isn't in the `good` set of data, even though both are from the same source and entered in the exact same way with openpyxl.

Which brings me round again to the question above. How can I make sure that the data I am entering doesn't have any of this xml content?

Comment: The exception does not relate to the code shown.

Comment: Quite true, which is why I'm trying to point out that some of the time it works, and other times it doesn't. I believe this is due to something in the data I am grabbing so I am looking for ways to sanitize the data that comes in.

Comment: Specifically: does the except relate directly to openpyxl? If so, please include relevant code. If not, please remove the tag. You might have more success with remote controlling Excel using xlwings.

Comment: I argue that it could relate to openpyxl due to how I am grabbing the data from the data spreadsheet. Is there some openpyxl setting that makes sure cell values do not contain any associated xml tags? data_only=True doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause.

I had a section where I was deleting an unused sheet using openpyxl.

```py
if days >= 150:
    sheet = 'MONTHLY'
    del wb['WEEKLY']
else:
    sheet = 'WEEKLY'
    del wb['MONTHLY']
```

As it turned out. anything with days <150 triggered the error above.

a working xml section would look like this

```xml
-<sheets>

<sheet r:id="rId1" sheetId="1" name="MONTHLY"/>

</sheets>


-<definedNames>

<definedName name="LOCAL_MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT" hidden="1" localSheetId="0">REPT(LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT,4)&LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_MONTH_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_DAY_FORMAT,2)&" "&REPT(LOCAL_HOUR_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_MINUTE_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_SECOND_FORMAT,2)</definedName>
```

and a non-working xml section (pre-repair) would look like this.

```xml
-<sheets>

<sheet r:id="rId1" state="visible" sheetId="1" name="WEEKLY"/>

</sheets>


-<definedNames>

<definedName name="LOCAL_MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT" localSheetId="1" hidden="1">REPT(LOCAL_YEAR_FORMAT,4)&LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_MONTH_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_DATE_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_DAY_FORMAT,2)&" "&REPT(LOCAL_HOUR_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_MINUTE_FORMAT,2)&LOCAL_TIME_SEPARATOR&REPT(LOCAL_SECOND_FORMAT,2)</definedName>
```

Important to note from these two bits is the `localSheetId`. For the Monthly ones with Days >150 removing the Weekly sheet, which was in list position 1, was no issue. Weekly ones would still have their `localSheetId="1"` set somewhere which would cause this section to mismatch as it became position 0 during the sheet deletion.

in the end removing the two deletion bits has 'fixed' this problem.

```py
if days >= 150:
    sheet = 'MONTHLY'
else:
    sheet = 'WEEKLY'
```

Although it would be nice to not have to keep the extraneous sheet.